# array push method not working properly

Tags: javascript, arrays, push

I am getting the following error for third line:

> `Can not set property accountName of Undefined`

Can anyone help?

```
var temp = [];
temp.accountId = newData.Account.Id;
temp.accountType = newData.Account.Type;
temp.accountholder.accountName = newData.Account.Name;

finaloutput.push(temp);
```

Comment: You are showing some interesting behaviour in Javascript with this. But I do not know if you set `temp.accountholder` explicitly before?;)

Comment: finaloutput array has accountholder

Comment: `temp.accountholder` is undefined. Make it not undefined and you won't have this problem.

Comment: This has nothing to do with `.push()`. If you remove that line, you'll get the same error.

Comment: It is already defined. All the properties are defined.

Comment: @user3421352: It is not defined in the code in your question.

Comment: But where did you define it? You do not show it.

Comment: Why do you use an array in a way an object would be used? I'm sure many people would find that confusing.

Answer (score 1):

set temp.accountholder in advance.

```
var temp =[];
temp.accountId = newData.Account.Id;
temp.accountType = newData.Account.Type;
temp.accountholder = {};     
temp.accountholder.accountName = newData.Account.Name;

finaloutput.push(temp);
```

Comment: The `temp.accountholder ||` can be removed. It doesn't do anything useful there.

Comment: That's right. Temp is declared right before so there isn't any risk of overwriting existing data

Comment: The funny part is, you can also do `temp.accountholder = []`. One visit to Stackoverflow and the mysticism is shining again! %)P